# A method to print linked list in reverse/backward order in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm writing a class called LList and in the class I defined a couple of methods. I am having issue with writing a method to print the linked list in backward order.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, nextNode=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNode = nextNode

class LList(object):

    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, node):

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
            self.size += 1
        else:
            # set new nodes pointer to old head
            node.nextNode = self.head
            # reset head to new node
            self.head = node
            self.size +=1

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def printLL(self):
        mynode = self.head
        c = 0
        while mynode:
            c += 1
            print(mynode.data, c)
            mynode = mynode.nextNode

#a method for class that prints list backwards.       
    def reverse(self):


#main program

    MyList = LList()
    MyList.insert(Node("NJ"))
    MyList.insert(Node("NR"))
    MyList.insert(Node("OH"))

    # Use my print method
    MyList.printLL()
    #print in reverse
    MyList.reverse()
```

Comment: Why don't you try something first and show us the code?

Answer (score 7):

```
class Node(object):

          def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
              self.data = data
              self.next = next_node

       def ReversePrint(head):
           if head == None:
              return
           else:
             ReversePrint(head.next)
             print(head.data)
```

Let's take an example Linked List: 1->2->3
Walking through the code, the function ReversePrint is given a link to the head of our Linked List, which is 1. We see that head is not equal to null so we move to the second line of the code, which is the first recursive call to head.next, which is 2. Again we see that this new "head" is not equal to null, so we do a second recursive call, this time passing the node that contains 3. We see that this new "head" is not equal to null, so we do a third recursive call on head.next, which is null in this case. So we return, since we hit our base case. We are now back in our second recursive call, and we move to the line of code that comes after the recursive call, which is the print statement. We print 3. Since this recursive call is now complete, we move back to the first recursive call, and print 2. Finally, we are back in our initial function call, and we print 1. Therefore, successfully printing our Linked List in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless you have a double-linked list, your best option is to traverse the whole linked list saving everything in memory and then print it.

This could be a draft of your code:

```
def print_reversed(self):

    node = self.head
    values = []
    while node:
        values.append(node.data)
        node = node.nextNode

    for value in reversed(values):
        print(value)
```

This somehow defeates the purpose of a linked list. You could do it recursively as well, but that would look messy IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that your issue is due to the fact that there is no efficient way to iterate backwards over a singly-linked list.

I've enhanced your code slightly by the use of some magic methods (aka [dunder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html) methods): methods whose names (usually) begin and end with double underscores. You can read about them in the docs under [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

An object's `__str__` method gets called when the object is passed to the `str` built-in function (which happens implicitly when you attempt to print the object). If an object doesn't have a `__str__` method its `__repr__` method is called; it's generally a good idea to define at least one of those two methods, otherwise when you try to print your object the default `__repr__` method inherited from the generic `object` will be called.

I've changed your `getSize` method to `__len__`, which gets called when an object is passed to the `len` built-in function.

An object's `__iter__` method gets called when it's passed to the `iter` built-in function, either explicitly or when you attempt to iterate over the object in some kind of `for` loop, or when you pass it to `list` or similar constructors. It generally works in conjunction with the `__next__` method, which is (unfortunately) named `next` in Python 2. When an object has these methods it's relatively easy to iterate over it in various ways.

To do the reverse printing we can simply pass the instance to `list`, and pass the resulting list to `reversed`, which returns an iterator that iterates backwards over its list argument.

The code below is written for Python 2; change the `next` method to `__next__` for Python 3.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, nextNode=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNode = nextNode

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class LList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.current = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, node):
        if self.head is not None:
            # set new node's pointer to old head
            node.nextNode = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.size += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.head
        return self

    def next(self):
        current = self.current
        if current is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current = current.nextNode
            return current

    def printLL(self):
        for i, node in enumerate(self, 1):
            print(node, i)

    # print the list backwards
    def reverse_print(self):
        c = len(self)
        for node in reversed(list(self)):
            print(node, c)
            c -= 1


# main program
mylist = LList()
mylist.insert(Node("NJ"))
mylist.insert(Node("NR"))
mylist.insert(Node("OH"))

print(len(mylist))

# print forwards
mylist.printLL()

#print the nodes using a list comprehension
print([str(node) for node in mylist])

#print in reverse
mylist.reverse_print()
```

**output**

```
3
OH 1
NR 2
NJ 3
['OH', 'NR', 'NJ']
NJ 3
NR 2
OH 1
```

Comment: getting a complaint that 'self' is not iterable

Comment: @Oliver Really? Is that the **exact** error message? What version of Python are you using? FWIW, the code runs perfectly for me on Python 3.6.0, once I change the name of the `next` method to `__next__`, as mentioned above. If I try to run that code unchanged on Python 3.6 I get this error message: `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'LList'`

Comment: Using Python 3.5.3

Comment: @Oliver Did you change the name of the `LList.next` method to `__next__`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using two loops. One for looping whole list and other for going to the specific node with respect to the main loop and printing it.
Count() returns the number of nodes. When the count has 0 value the loop of nodes stops at last node because of (self.Count() - count) and prints it. Just like that it goes backward.

```
def reverse(self):
    for count in range(self.Count()+1):
       
        iteration = 0       
        printval = self.head

        while printval != None:
            if iteration == (self.Count() - count):  
                break
            printval = printval.next
            iteration = iteration + 1
        print(printval.name)
```