# pythonic linked list comprehension

Tags: python, linked-list

Is there a better and pythonic way of writing the snippet of code below? I don't see a way of using a list comprehension.

The context is that I have a linked list of nodes and in the associated __str__() routine I want to turn the thread into a list and print the result

```
temp = []
node = firstNode
while node:
    temp.append(str(node))
    node = node.next
return '{' + '->'.join(temp) + '}'
```

**Post Script**

Thank you for the links; they gave me the idea for this solution which I find rather amusing. I think it's elegant but not obvious so it isn't pythonic.

```
foo = lambda x: [str(x)]+foo(x.next) if x else []
return '{' + '->'.join(foo(firstNode)) + '}'
```

Explanation ... foo is a recursive lambda function. If I were to write

```
foo = lambda x: [x] if x else []
```

then foo(***None***) would return the empty list and return a list containing x for any other value. If I make it recursive

```
foo = lambda x: [x]+foo(x.next) if x else []
```

Then foo keeps calling itself on the next node in the linked list until it reaches the last one. It returns the empty list from the last call and then prepends the current node to the accumulating list until it has completely climbed out of the recursive calls. The code in my solution does the same but turns the node into a string before it does the prepend operation.

Comment: `return` from where?

Comment: Considering you don't start with a python list, but are trying to make one, a list comprehension does not seem a viable approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020037/how-to-walk-up-a-linked-list-using-a-list-comprehension

Comment: This might give you a few ideas. :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34266794/4014959